# FFT calculation problem

Tags: fft

Now I'm trying to study about FFT with the following example.
[image]

I just implement into excel to see the how does it work, But the results are different at all as the below image.

[image]

how do I get the result correct?

Comment: check your formula copying, it seems that your formula is stuck at A1

Comment: @AlexTP No, it doesn't. I found the first term is very small  than second term.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample rate is too slow. You are sampling at 1 Hz.

You need to sample at at least twice the highest frequency which, in this case, would be 4 kHz. To be safe, I'd go with 5 kHz.

The value in A2 should not be 1, it should be 1/5000. A3 should be 2/5000, etc.

The reason why you see the sample is that it's a periodic wave form and you always sample at the same spot in the period.

Comment: Thanks, then would you letting me know how do you get 4kHz? and I'm wondering how do you know the highest frequency

Comment: @sympony: Your signal consists of two sine waves: one at 1 kHz and one at 2 kHz. According to the sampling theorem you need to sample at twice the highest frequency. If you don't know that means, I recommend taking a basic class on digital signal processing. I'm not trying to discourage you, but  you need some basic mathematical fundamentals, otherwise you won't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your Excel formula to generate the sampled sequence
$$x_{in}[n] = \sin(2\pi 1000 n T_s) + 0.5 \sin(2 \pi 2000 n T_s) $$
is wrong. Where as your **A** holds the place of $n$ in the equation, the $T_s$ is missing in your Excel formula (or is taken as the default of $1$, when it's missing as Hilmar already stated).

Hence your correct formula should include the term for $F_s= 8000$ or multiplication by $T_s = 1/8000$ inside the $\sin(\cdot)$ parts.